# Applying SQL LIKE statement on UTF coded character giving no results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a json column in my sql table, and I am using LIKE% to search for values in it, and it is working perfect with English chars, but when searching for Greek chars, it breaks because Greek chars are encoded in the table, however I tried to encode it using json_encode (PHP) before applying Like statement, but still fails
here's how it is stored in the DB

```
{"text":"\u0391\u03bd\u03b1\u03bc\u03bf\u03bd\u03ae \u0395\u03bd\u03b7\u03bc\u03ad\u03c1\u03c9\u03c3\u03b7\u03c2 \u03b1\u03c0\u03cc"}
```

and this is the query applied

```
select * from tableX where ("text"::text like '%\u0391\u03bd\u03b1\u03bc\u03bf\u03bd\u03ae \u0395\u03bd\u03b7\u03bc\u03ad\u03c1\u03c9\u03c3\u03b7\u03c2 \u03b1\u03c0\u03cc%')
```

is there something I have missed?
I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: What's the database? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Oh yes PostgreSQL, I will update the post

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but curious if `ilike` would work?

Comment: Those are escape sequences, not Unicode. This page is Unicode which is why I can type `Αυτό Εδώ` without escaping anything, knowing it will appear correctly. There's absolutely no reason to use escape sequences to store non US-ASCII when we have Unicode

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you mean?: `select 'naïve' ilike 'naï%'; t`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no, I meant how `naïve` would appear when stored by that application. While it's an English word, it can't be represented by the US-ASCII character set. That application would have to either mangle the word or escape parts of it. Which is meaningless, as JSON strings are already Unicode, they don't need escaping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with actual Greek text, not escape sequences. Just like PHP, Python, C++, JavaScript, Java, C#, the escape sequences you use in source code or see in a debugger don't really appear in the string. They're replaced by the actual character by the compiler. The same happens with JSON deserializers.

That means that

```
{"text":"\u0391\u03bd\u03b1\u03bc\u03bf\u03bd\u03ae \u0395\u03bd\u03b7\u03bc\u03ad\u03c1\u03c9\u03c3\u03b7\u03c2 \u03b1\u03c0\u03cc"}
```

is identical to

```
{"text":"Αναμονή Ενημέρωσης από"}
```

Try

```
select * from tableX where text->>'text' like '%Αναμονή%'
```

JSON strings are Unicode so there's no reason to use escape sequences. When escape sequences are used, parsers replace them with the actual character.

---

For reference, from the [RFC8259: The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259)

In the [Strings section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7)

```
      string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark

      char = unescaped /
          escape (
              %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
              %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
              %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
              %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
              %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
              %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
              %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
              %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
              %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX

      escape = %x5C              ; \

      quotation-mark = %x22      ; "

      unescaped = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-10FFFF
```

That means all Unicode characters except 8 *can* appear unescaped.

From [8.1 Character Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-8.1)

> JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed
> ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8